Superset viz-plugin does not work. setting up superset with docker-compose is ok, then viz-plugin does nothing
I've been looking for a solution to use superset viz plugin with docker compose but nothing works...
Does anyone has idea how to do it?
https://preset.io/blog/building-custom-viz-plugins-in-superset-v2/
I've been trying to make it non-dev, dev, version 2.0.0, using yo@4, yo@5 but I was beaten all the time.
